# each data in mongodb local.oplog.rs, is it a standard bsonobject structure

Tags: mongodb, spark-streaming, mongodb-oplog

I use spark mongo-connector to sync data from mongodb collection to hdfs file,
my code works fine if the collection is read through mongos, but when it comes to local.oplog.rs, a replica collection only could be read through mongod, it gives me exception:

Caused by: com.mongodb.hadoop.splitter.SplitFailedException: Unable to calculate input splits: couldn't find index over splitting key { _id: 1 }

I think the data structure is different between oplog.rs and normal collection, oplog.rs doesn't have "_id" property, so the newAPIHadoopRDD can not work nomally, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Document structure is a bit different in oplog.rs. You will find your actual document in "o" field of oplog document.

Example oplog document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("586e74b70dec07dc3e901d5f"),
"ts" : Timestamp(1459500301, 6436),
"h" : NumberLong("5511242317261841397"),
"v" : 2,
"op" : "i",
"ns" : "urDB.urCollection",
"o" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("567ba035e4b01052437cbb27"),
      .... 
     .... this is your original document.

      }
```

}

Use "ns" and "o" of oplog.rs to get your expected collection and document.

Comment: @user6376657 If it helps, could you please mark it as best answer?